# what does it mean to hard-brick a device?

Tags: hardware-failure, flashing

I read people complaining that certain EFI-enabled Samsung laptops can be accidentally 'bricked' when trying to install an OS or when using certain programs in them, which doesn't happen with BIOS mode. The way I read it, it seems software can cause the hardware to be irreparably `bricked` (hard-brick). What does it mean in hardware terms to irreparably damage a laptop due to a software or firmware failure? Is it not possible to re-flash the firmware, even it that means opening it up and using special tools?

EDIT: I understand that even if it takes a lot of effort to unbrick, that would still be considered a "soft brick", not a "hard brick". For example, for routers, sometimes the solution is to open...

> ... the case, shorting some jumper pins on the board, then connecting the
>   router by the USB cable to an old PC with USB 1.1 hardware, running a
>   special DOS level program supplied by the manufacturer, and powering
>   the router up. This procedure will flash the router to factory
>   settings and original firmware.
>   (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brick_%28electronics%29#Systems)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brick_%28electronics%29 is a good starting point.

Comment: ^^ especially the bit about soft-bricks and hard-bricks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While software can cause permanent hardware changes and/or damages (specially the software controlling frequencies/voltages/etc or burning one time programmable fuses) in my experience (and I work in embedded systems development industry - I get to see a lot of bricked devices) very few "bricks" are really irreparable. Usually the difference between "soft" and "hard" bricking is in the complexity of the recovery procedure - unbricking of a hard-bricked device usually requires special skills and/or equipment.

As for the specific problem mentioned (UEFI implementation bug in some Samsung notebooks) - it seems that clearing NVRAM fixes the problem (it reverts the BIOS/UEFI mode setting to its default value, which is luckily the "BIOS").